# Why sometimes function \prop_item:N returns empty values?

Tags: expl3

I want to work with some environments and check property values for this. But I have a problem, because function `prop_item` returns an empty value. Help me please fix this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \g__env_str
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g__env_prop {temp@env=true}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { NV }

\newenvironment{temp@env}
 {
  \iow_term:x
   {
    item~\prop_item:NV \g__env_prop {\g__env_str}~environment~\g__env_str
   }
\str_case:nnF
   {
    \prop_item:NV {\g__env_prop}{\g__env_str}
   }
   {
    {true}
{\iow_term:x{test}}
}
{
  \iow_term:x
{no test}
}
}
{}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{temp@env}
 {
  \str_gset:Nn \g__env_str {temp@env}
 }
\AfterEndEnvironment{temp@env}
 {
  \str_gclear:N \g__env_str
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{temp@env}
\end{temp@env}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what do you expect this to do? it makes no pdf output and makes a message `item  environment temp@env` on the console.

Comment: @David Carlisle I expected to get message item true environment temp@env and after that message test. I not need now in output of pdf.

Comment: The braces of the arguments of \str_case:nnF look wrong, and whatever this is supposed to do you will run into problems if such environments are nested. And you are imho not expanding correctly.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy really you post a tangled collection of code like that without saying what it is intended to do or what output you got, it really makes it very hard to help at all.

Comment: perhaps you should start by giving a top level description of the intended use case here, then someone could suggest how to code it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no item named `\g__env_str` in the property list.

You want to use `\prop_item:NV` in order to extract the *value* of the string variable. Similarly, you need `\str_case_e:nn` in the second part.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3,etoolbox}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\str_new:N \g__env_str
\prop_gset_from_keyval:Nn \g__env_prop {temp@env=true}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \prop_item:Nn { NV }

\newenvironment{temp@env}
 {
  \iow_term:x
   {
    item~\prop_item:NV \g__env_prop {\g__env_str}~environment~\g__env_str
   }
  \str_case_e:nn
   {
    \prop_item:NV \g__env_prop \g__env_str
   }
   {
    {true}{\iow_term:n {test}}
   }
 }
 {}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{temp@env}
 {
  \str_gset:Nn \g__env_str {temp@env}
 }
\AfterEndEnvironment{temp@env}
 {
  \str_gclear:N \g__env_str
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{temp@env}
\end{temp@env}

\end{document}
```

The terminal will show

```
item true environment temp@env
true
```

Comment: Yes,it almost what i want,but i want to use TF function for str_case,because in my code it happends checking on tru/false. Yes,now all in termenal correct,but in case i have false part of code,even if i have true value in string.

Comment: @AleksandrKozlovskiy You can use `\str_case_e:nnF`